# How to format the casper.log output?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way that to format the log output to include timestamp in casper.log?

For example:

```
casper.log("some debug message", "debug");
```

stdout: [debug] [phantom] [2016-04-26T10:00:00.000] some debug message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

casper has a logFormats object that is currently [not documented](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/942).

Since I hate using non-documented features I would advise you to just overload the log method to do something like this.

```
var _oldLog = casper.log;
casper.log = function(message, level, space) {
  var message_with_date = "[" + new Date() + "] " + message;
  _oldLog.call(this, message_with_date, level, space);
};
```